# PHP include files in separate directory

Tags: php

I have an `app` folder that has an `includes` and a `public` folder.

Like so:

[image: app folder]

The includes folder has the following files:

`bootstrap.php`
`config.php`

`config.php` has the following code:

```
<?php
return array(
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => '',
        'db'        => 'imagebox2016'
    );
```

`boostrap.php` has the following code:

```
<?php
// bootstrap code
$config = require_once 'config.php';
$dsn = "mysql:host=$config[host];dbname=$config[db]";

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $config['username'], $config['password']);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

In the `public` folder there is a file called `signup.php`

It starts out like this and successfully runs:

```
<?php
require_once '../includes/bootstrap.php';
```

My question is when I include `boostrap.php` within `signup.php` how does `bootstrap.php` successfully include `config.php` when it is one level up and then one level down in the `includes` folder?

PHP [states](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

> Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given,
>   the include_path specified. If the file isn't found in the
>   include_path, include will finally check in the calling script's own
>   directory and the current working directory before failing. The
>   include construct will emit a warning if it cannot find a file

I have not modified my `include_path`

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) at the top of your file(s): `ini_set("display_errors", 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` and tell us what you get.

Comment: are you sure a _file_ can return something (without a function beeing called)?? make that array in config a var called `$config` and require `config.php` without assigning the return to a var.

Comment: Put the `error_reposting...` no errors come up. Code runs successfully and includes files with no problems. I just don't understand why it is successful.

Comment: I am sure a file can return something: "Also, it's possible to return values from included files. You can take the value of the include call as you would for a normal function. "

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: @RobertRocha Are you sure you show us your real code here? And you also look at the correct file?

Comment: Yes. Code runs with no errors. That is why I posted the code and pictures as above.

Comment: @RobertRocha The behavior is correct. You confuse “calling” script with “executing” script. You can try by setting `require_once ... bootstrap.php` to absolute path, place a `config.php` into `signup.php` directory and calling `signup.php` by commandline from outside `signup.php` dir: you will see that the included file is that from bootstrap dir, not from signup dir.

Comment: @fusion3k thanks for the input. I complete answer below would be better to improve this posting.